# Error in applying font size to iTextsharp PDF windows forms using C#

Tags: c#, itext

I am very new to C# and I am creating a small program to create PDF invoices. All I need to do is set the font size of my text within a table cell, however the recommended methods are not working at all. I am working in Visual Studio 2019 and using iTextSharp version 5.5.13.1. Here is my attempt:

```
PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(float.Parse("Quantity"), new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.NORMAL, Color.YELLOW)));
```

But I got an error:

> 'Font' is an ambiguous reference between System.Drawing.Font and
>   iTextSharp.text.Font`.

However I figured this one out in that I have to destinguish between which font source I am using (Not sure if I am saying this correctly.). So I tried the following:

```
PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(float.Parse("Quantity"), new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)));
```

But now I am getting an error:

> Argument 2: Cannot convert from iTextSharp.text.Font to
>   iTextSharp.text.Chunk.

All I want is to set the font size...

Comment: It seems to be a very simple error. Kindly check the type of parameters accepted to by constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Could you explain what you mean? Like I said, I am very new to C#... Like started this weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below method.

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Phrase", new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 16, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)));
```

Comment: 'Font' is an ambiguous reference between System.Drawing.Font and iTextSharp.text.Font`.

Comment: Can  you see my updated answer.. Or you can directly use `iTextSharp.text.Font` in place of `Font`

Comment: Ok, so I removed `using System.Drawing` and now the original error is gone, now I am getting` 'Font' does not contain a definition for 'NORMAL' and no accessible extension method 'NORMAL' accepting a first argument of type 'Font' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: do you have this line `using iTextSharp.text;`?

Comment: Yes: `using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
//using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509;`

Comment: which version of iTextSharp you have?

Comment: iTextSharp version 5.5.13.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215638/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-roelofco).